# Use of @Async with @Transactional method springboot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, asynchronous, transactions

I have @async method in my springboot controller which calls service method (async) and does some DB transactions. When this controllers @async method is called multiple times without time delay, it results in org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Controller

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/api/sms/sendmsgasync")
  public ResponseEntity<Boolean> sendSMSMessageAsync(@RequestBody MessageRequestDto messageRequestDto) {

    final Future<Boolean> booleanFuture = smsService.sendSingleMessageAsync(messageRequestDto, requestContext.getConversationId());
    log.debug("sendSMSMessageAsync {} <<<<", booleanFuture.isDone());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(true);
  }
```

service

```
 @Async
  @Override
  public Future<Boolean> sendSingleMessageAsync(MessageRequestDto messageRequestDto, String convId) {


    try {
      sendSingleMessage(messageRequestDto, convId);
    }
    catch (BadRequestException | NotFoundException | TwilioException e) {
      LOG.error("Error in sendSingleMessageAsync. Error logged to SMS Gateway db. Exception '" + e.getMessage() + "'", e);
    }
    return new AsyncResult<>(true);
  }
```

which then calls sendSingleMessage method in same service class in which calls NOT transnational methods to do database look up and adding db entry etc.

When this controllers @async method is called multiple times without time delay, it results in

> org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
>   Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire
>   JDBC Connection at  ...............
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:400)
>   ... 65 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is
>   not available, request timed out after 30000ms. at

Do I need to add "ThreadExecutor" with service @async method?

I am new to this so any pointers will be helpful

Comment: looks like your DB is down.

Comment: No DB was up as I was getting this error for some requests only ...seems like connections are not released due to multiple async calls using db connections

Comment: Looks like your connection pool has exhaused and given all the connections available. Can you enable debug logs for Hikar connection pool? This will give you more insight.
Look for something like [total=20, active=20, idle=0, waiting=0].
Also, make sure that connections are properly closed and returned to the pool. Check your transaction boundries.

Comment: using hikari? if so what's your config?  you should also show your JPA code.  are you cleaning up correctly?

Comment: why are you always returning 'true'? unless the value changes there's no need to return anything.

Comment: where's the @Transactional at?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation. After research, we found out that asynchronous threads were overwhelming the system. All threads were started in parallel and this depleted the JDBC connection pool. No connections were left for other threads, like controllers.

A first measure is to use a custom thread executor, that you can limit according to your resources.

```
    @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
    public ExecutorService taskExecutor() {
        // adjust this value to your CPU cores
        // and to the JDBC connection pool size
        int maxThreads = 4;
        return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxThreads);
    }
```

Make sure this task executor is used for async methods:

```
    @Async("taskExecutor")  
    public void myBackgroundThread() {
        ...
    }
```

In your *application.properties* file, set the connection pool size for the Hikari datasource. The default is 10.

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
```

Take care that the thread pool for background processes is smaller than the pool for database connections. Otherwise foreground threads will suffer.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the reason is one of the 2 below, taking that DB is connectable:

**1) Insufficient size of connection pool.**
Check the value of the property **spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize** (default is 20) to be sure that number is enough. Think about how many requests could be processed simultaneously in your app, taking that each thread uses it's own connection.

**2) Connection leak in your app.**
Check that your connections are closed properly (returned to the pool in this case). Always call connection.close() in **finally** block or use try-with-resources to avoid leaking on exceptions.